# $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Show that $S \circ T$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be linear transformations. Show that $S \circ T$ is not invertible.

Thoughts on this problem:

$S$ can be represented with a $3\times2$ matrix and T can be represented with a $2\times 3$ matrix. ST is defined and it is a $3 \times 3$ matrix. It can be inverted if its determinant is non-zero. However, since the matrix $ST$ isn't actually known (because the transformations aren't given), I can't just invoke the determinant. I assume there must be some **other** invertibility condition, that I don't know about, which is broken by $ST$.

Comment: Intuition: $T$ loses at least a dimension worth of data and $S$ can't possibly bring it back

Comment: @qbert I'm confused, isn't it true that R^3 and R^2 have the same cardinality, so there must exist a bijection between their sets?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 These are linear maps, not arbitrary functions. A bijection $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be linear.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I remember being confused by the same thing. But note that I said a dimension's worth, which is a statement about numbers of linearly independent vectors, not cardinalities. As Hayden says, linear maps treat subspaces in a special way (compatible) way, and being injective as a linear map also involves not collapsing any nontrivial vectors to $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\ker(T)\subset \ker(ST).
$$
It suffices to show that $\ker(T)$ is non-trivial. However this is clear since
$$
3=\dim \ker(T)+\dim\text{im}(T)
$$
by the rank-nullity theorem and
$$
\dim\text{im}(T)\leq 2
$$

Answer (score 2):

The maximum rank $T$ can have is $2$ because its image is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The maximum rank $S$ can have is $2$ because $\operatorname{rank}S + \operatorname{nullity}S=2$. That means that $$\operatorname{rank}ST\leq \max\{\operatorname{rank}S,\operatorname{rank}T\}\leq 2$$
I claim that $ST$ needs to have rank $3$ in order to be invertible. Like you said, this is another invertibility condition. Think for a moment about why this must be true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $S\circ T$ is invertible, it is a bijection. What can you say if the composition of two maps is injective? is surjective?

Comment: I like the path where you're leading me. However, the problem doesn't say anything about $S$ and $T$ being injective. And assuming both $S$ and $T$ are injective, why can't it be surjective?

Comment: There's a general result in set theory: if $S\circ T$ is injective, $T$ is necessarily injective. If it is surjective, $S$ is surjective.